# Search in vector<std::pair<int, vector<int> > >

Tags: c++

I would like to search within a `vector<std::pair<int, vector<int> > >`. This won't work due to the vector parameters:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > > myVec;
iterator = find(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), i);
```

Search would be on the first `std::pair` template parameter (`int`), in order to get the vector associated with it.

Comment: There's no such thing as vector<int, vector<int>> at least not in C++. Maybe vector<vector<int>>(vector of vectors) or vector<vector<int>*>?

Comment: In what way is one of the vector element associated with the `int`? Is it an index: `foo[i]`?

Comment: Did you mean `map< int, vector<int> >` ?

Comment: It looks like u need maps and not vectors

Comment: @NIX What do you mean by "This is the declaration that I did". It's obviously wrong; this is how vector is declared ​template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector; so the second template parameter is the allocator class which cannot be also a vector; and who voted the question up?!

Comment: `vector< int, vector<int> >` won't compile.

Comment: @junjanes it seems that it's his own version of vector; NIX: shouldn't name your containers as the standard ones - as you can see it "confuses" people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make do with the following (pretty ugly) functoid:

```
struct FindFirst {
    FindFirst(int i) : toFind(i) { }
    int toFind;
    bool operator() 
        ( const std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > &p ) {
            return p.first==toFind;
    }
};
```

using it like this ( I couldn't get bind2nd to work - that's why I used the c'tor ):

```
int valueToFind = 4;
std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), FindFirst(valueToFind));
```

---

I think what you would like is a *map*:

```
std::map< int, vector< int > > foo;
```

You can then **add elements**, search by **key** etc:

```
int key = 4; //This will be the key
vector<int> value(5, 4); //Fill some values (5 4's in this case) into the vector

foo[key]=value; //Adds the pair to the map. Alternatively;
foo.insert( make_pair(key, value) ); //Does the same thing (in this context)
```

Looking at the way you've done things though, you might be wanting a `std::multimap` (which allows multiple values to have the same key) [Class docs here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/)

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > > myVec;
```

This requires C++0x for the lambda expression:

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> pair_type
std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [i](pair_type const& pair)
{ return pair.first == i; });
```

If you're not using C++0x then either roll out your own loop or use something like Boost.Phoenix/Boost.Lambda.

**Or**, for both cases, why not use `std::map`?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to *map* an `int` to a *vector* of `int`.

So try `map<int, vector<int> >`.

Answer (score 1):

The second template parameter of a vector is the allocator - your compiler can probably puzzle out what you wanted to say, the declaration is wrong anyway. What you probably want is some sort of map type, like iammilind suggested.

Comment: it is not wrong since I implemented it. And inserted the data into it. What i want is to find an int from the first parameter That's it.

Comment: so vector is not std::vector is your own "twisted version of vector wanting actually to be an associative container" thingy?

Comment: @NIX: Just because you wrote down some code and the compiler guessed at what you meant does not mean it's correct. Obviously, the vector does not behave as you wanted it to, so something must be wrong here. And it probably won't be a standard implementation people have been using for years, if not decades.